# How to get log of Unity container Resolve method?

Tags: logging, unity-container

I'm now converting my project from homemade container-like structure, to Unity. I'm at the stage where it is building, but have some configuration problems.
After last change project began failing without exception(simply system crash message after a couple of seconds lag). My experience tells me, that this is because of stack overflow. I think I heard somewhere that there is a way to enable logging of unity resolution process. So I'll be able to see where it gets stuck, but I can`t find this info anymore.

Comment: Would be good to get an answer to the actual headline question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET, you can enable your debugger to stop on StackOverflowExceptions.

Comment: Debugger would already stopped there if it could. But whole process crashes even under debug.